# php - include_once seems to print the desired page into the html

Tags: php, html, include

My problem is that I try to include a class using `include_once();` but instead of including the desired file, it prints the code in the file straight into the source html so the code appears on my webpage.

This is the code:

```
<?
include_once('php/class.loadClients.php');
$client = new loadClient();
$client->connect();
?>
```

I'm not sure why its doing this as I've used `include_once();` elsewhere in this page and it works fine:

```
include_once('php/class.register.php');
```

---

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `php/class.loadClients.php`, and add `<?` to the beginning of it.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Paulpro's answer: if his solution does not work your server might not have short tags enabled ( `<?` vs `<?php` ). Use the full `<?php` tag.

Comment: This should be a comment.